# Looking at single assertions in z3py

Tags: python, z3, z3py

Having declared assertions on a solver, how can I get and exploit single assertions out of all of them? So, if `s.assertions` could be transformed to a list, we could access a single statement. This can not be done. I explain by the following assertions on 'BitVecs' and what I'd like to get out.

```py
from z3 import *

s = Solver()
x,y,z,w   = BitVecs("x y z w",7)    #rows
a,b,c,d,e = BitVecs("a b c d e",7)  #cols

constr = [x&a==a,x&b==b,x&c!=c,x&d!=d,x&e!=e,
          y&a==a,y&b!=b,y&c!=c,y&d!=d,y&e==e,
          z&a!=a,z&b==b,z&c==c,z&d==d,z&e!=e,
          w&a!=a,w&b==b,w&c!=c,w&d==d,w&e==e ]

s.add(constr)

R = [x,y,z,w]
C = [a,b,c,d,e]

s.assertions()
```

I need a matrix (list of lists) that indicates wheter a `R`,`C`-pair has `==` or `!=` type of 'constr'. So, the matrix for the declared `constr` is

```py
[[1,1,0,0,0],
 [1,0,0,0,1],
 [0,1,1,1,0],
 [0,1,0,1,1]]
```

.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is rather an odd thing to want to do. You *are* constructing these assertions yourself, so it's much better to simply keep track of how you constructed them to find out what they contain.

If these are coming from some other source (possible, I suppose), then you'll have to "parse" them back into AST form and walk their structure to answer questions of the form "what are the variables", "what are the connectives" etc. Doing so will require an understanding of how z3py internally represents these objects. While this is possible, I very much doubt it's something you want to do unless you're working on a library that's supposed to handle everything. (i.e., since you know what you're constructing, simply keep track of it elsewhere.)

But, if you do want to analyze these expressions, the way to go is to study the AST structure. You'll have to become familiar with the contents of this file: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/src/api/python/z3/z3.py, and especially the functions [decl](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/8e2f09b517ae84b2f70d0e4af74df95c8ecf38b2/src/api/python/z3/z3.py#L1037) and [children](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/8e2f09b517ae84b2f70d0e4af74df95c8ecf38b2/src/api/python/z3/z3.py#L1089) amongst others.

Comment: Thanks @alias for your valuable guidance! It's actually not from an external source. I wanted to handle instance constraints in alternative ways., but I see now that this makes not much sense in my case. Your reference on [decl](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/8e2f09b517ae84b2f70d0e4af74df95c8ecf38b2/src/api/python/z3/z3.py#L1037)  and  [children](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/8e2f09b517ae84b2f70d0e4af74df95c8ecf38b2/src/api/python/z3/z3.py#L1089) is helpful too.